# Change the icon color in LibreOffice Calc

Tags: 14.04, libreoffice

There appears to be no way of changing icon color in a calc chart. After creating an XY scatter plot, I can select "format data series" and can change the icon symbol and size, but not the color. There is an drop-down for line color, but when I do not have lines displayed this drop-down menu is grayed out.

I have found that I can add lines to my chart, change the color of the lines, then remove the lines and I will have changed the color of the icons, but there should be a direct way to change icon color (and there used to be in previous versions).

I am using Libreoffice calc version 4.2.3.3, Build ID: 420m0(Build:3). Running on Ubuntu 14.04.